# How to prevent a memory leak

Tags: c, memory

I am supposed to write code that raised a two-dimensional matrix to a certain power, and I'm also supposed to not let any memory leaks occur. I have written this function (it uses another function, product, that I wrote but you can ignore that) and I can't see where a memory leak would occur, but I'm also very new to this. Any help pointing out how I can make this more efficient would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
int **matrixPower(int **A, int size, int n){
      int **a = NULL;
      a = (int **)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        a[i] = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
      }
      a = A;
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        a = product(a, A, size);
      }
      return a;
    }
```

Comment: Hint: a leak occurs every time when you have a `malloc` that does not have a corresponding `free`.

Comment: To make your code easier to work with, store the matrix in a struct which also contains the current dimensions

Comment: put `malloc` and `free` in the same code block will make your life easier

Comment: @bpceee: Sometimes functions return memory that the caller is responsible for.  It's far from rare in C

Comment: @EdS. you are right~

Answer (score 1):

[dasbllinkenlight's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727150/how-to-prevent-a-memory-leak#comment42043009_26727150) is correct. As long as you remember to delete each pointer you create there shouldn't be a memory leak.
Think about this line

```
a = (int **)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
...
a = A;
```

You're creating a pointer to a list of pointers and putting them in `a`.
You are then making pointers to int arrays in this array of pointers.
After this you are making `a=A`.
Unless I'm missing something here it looks like you created a list of pointers and then removed the reference.

Comment: But don't delete the one you're returning!

Answer (score 0):

You allocate 'a' as an array of int pointer of length size

Then for each element in the array you allocate an array of int pointers of length size.

Then you do

```
a = A;
```

where A is is a int** coming from outside the function. This overwrites your only pointer to all that memory you just allocated. Memory Leak there.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of A=a, you wrongly assigned a=A. So you created 2D array and overwrite that 2D pointer with some other value. Here the created pointer is lost. This caused the memory leak issue